# Java | Fit parent's width inside JScrollPane

Tags: java

```
package Rainbow;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Entry
{
    public static void main(String[] Q)
    {
        JFrame R = new JFrame();
        JPanel P = new JPanel()
        {
            public Dimension getMaximumSize()
            { return new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,getMinimumSize().height); }
        };
        P.setLayout(new BoxLayout(P,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JTextArea A = new JTextArea(
                "VERYLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONGLONG");
        A.setEditable(false);
        A.setLineWrap(true);
        P.add(new Label("Text"));
        P.add(A);
        JScrollPane S = new JScrollPane(P);
        R.add(S);
        R.setSize(300,300);
        R.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        R.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It is how it looks on startup.
[StartUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcxSY.png)

After reducing the Frame's size.
[Reduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muhS8.png)
The JTextArea inside would not reduce its size.

I'm using JTextArea here because it seems  to be the easiest way to do line wrap on a component. So how to solve it? Or is there an alternate way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize TextArrea too. Here are some related examples for your question: [Java JTextArea that auto-resizes and scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843493/java-jtextarea-that-auto-resizes-and-scrolls).

Example described where JPanel is used and how we can do it:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  //give your JPanel a BorderLayout

JTextArea text = new JTextArea(); 
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text); //place the JTextArea in a scroll pane
panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER); //add the JScrollPane to the panel
// CENTER will use up all available space
```